# Using a grouped z-score over a rolling window

Tags: python-polars

I would like to calculate a z-score over a bin based on the data of a rolling look-back period.

Example
Todays visitor amount during [9:30-9:35) should be z-score normalized based off the (mean, std) of the last 3 days of visitors that visited during [9:30-9:35).

My current attempts both raise InvalidOperationError. Is there a way in polars to calculate this?

```py
import polars as pl

def z_score(col: str, over: str, alias: str):
    # calculate z-score normalized `col` over `over`
    return (
        (pl.col(col)-pl.col(col).over(over).mean()) / pl.col(col).over(over).std()
    ).alias(alias)

df = pl.from_dict(
    {
        "timestamp": pd.date_range("2019-12-02 9:30", "2019-12-02 12:30", freq="30s").union(
            pd.date_range("2019-12-03 9:30", "2019-12-03 12:30", freq="30s")
        ),
        "visitors": [(e % 2) + 1 for e in range(722)]
    }
# 5 minute bins for grouping [9:30-9:35) -> 930
).with_column(
    pl.col("timestamp").dt.truncate(every="5m").dt.strftime("%H%M").cast(pl.Int32).alias("five_minute_bin")
).with_column(
    pl.col("timestamp").dt.truncate(every="3d").alias("daytrunc")
)

# normalize visitor amount for each 5 min bin over the rolling 3 day window using z-score.


# not rolling but also wont work (InvalidOperationError: window expression not allowed in aggregation)
# df.with_column(
#     z_score("visitors", "five_minute_bin", "normalized").over("daytrunc")
# )

# won't work either (InvalidOperationError: window expression not allowed in aggregation)
#df.groupby_rolling(index_column="daytrunc", period="3i").agg(z_score("visitors", "five_minute_bin", "normalized"))
```

For an example of 4 days of data with four data-points each lying in two time-bins ({0,0} - {0,1}), ({1,0} - {1,1})

Input:

```
Day 0: x_d0_{0,0}, x_d0_{0,1}, x_d0_{1,0}, x_d0_{1,1}
Day 1: x_d1_{0,0}, x_d1_{0,1}, x_d1_{1,0}, x_d1_{1,1}
Day 2: x_d2_{0,0}, x_d2_{0,1}, x_d2_{1,0}, x_d2_{1,1}
Day 3: x_d3_{0,0}, x_d3_{0,1}, x_d3_{1,0}, x_d3_{1,1}
```

Output:

```
Day 0: norm_x_d0_{0,0} = nan, norm_x_d0_{0,1} = nan, norm_x_d0_{1,0} = nan, norm_x_d0_{1,1} = nan
Day 1: norm_x_d1_{0,0} = nan, norm_x_d1_{0,1} = nan, norm_x_d1_{1,0} = nan, norm_x_d1_{1,1} = nan
Day 2: norm_x_d2_{0,0} = nan, norm_x_d2_{0,1} = nan, norm_x_d2_{1,0} = nan, norm_x_d2_{1,1} = nan
Day 3: norm_x_d3_{0,0} = (x_d3_{0,0} - np.mean([x_d0_{0,0}, x_d0_{0,1}, X_d1_{0,0}, ..., x_d3_{0,1}]) / np.std([x_d0_{0,0}, x_d0_{0,1}, X_d1_{0,0}, ...,  x_d3_{0,1}])) , ... ,
```

Comment: I think the `by` argument in `groupby_rolling` is what you are looking for: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.groupby_rolling.html#polars.DataFrame.groupby_rolling. Set by to `five_minute_bin` and create a date column and use that as the argument for `index_column`.

Comment: @jvz you mean like this? 
`
df.groupby_rolling(
    index_column="daytrunc", 
    period="3i", 
    by="five_minute_bin"
).agg(
    ((pl.col("visitors") - pl.col("visitors").mean()) / pl.col("visitors").std()).alias("norm")
)
`
How would I get the original dataframe format from there with the normalized visitors column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key here is to use `over` to restrict your calculations to the five minute bins and then use the `rolling` functions to get the rolling mean and standard deviation over days restricted by those five minute bin keys. `five_minute_bin` works as in your code and I believe that a truncated `day_bin` is necessary so that, for example, 9:33 on one day will include 9:31 both 9:34 on the same and 9:31 from 2 days ago.

```py
days = 5
pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": pl.concat(
            [
                pl.date_range(
                    datetime(2019, 12, d, 9, 30), datetime(2019, 12, d, 12, 30), "30s"
                )
                for d in range(2, days + 2)
            ]
        ),
        "visitors": [(e % 2) + 1 for e in range(days * 361)],
    }
).with_columns(
    five_minute_bin=pl.col("timestamp").dt.truncate(every="5m").dt.strftime("%H%M"),
    day_bin=pl.col("timestamp").dt.truncate(every="1d"),
).with_columns(
    standardized_visitors=(
        (
            pl.col("visitors")
            - pl.col("visitors").rolling_mean("3d", by="day_bin", closed="right")
        )
        / pl.col("visitors").rolling_std("3d", by="day_bin", closed="right")
    ).over("five_minute_bin")
)
```

Now, that said, when trying out the code for this, I found polars doesn't handle non-unique values in the by-column in the rolling function correctly, so that the same values in the same 5-minute bin don't end up as the same standardized values. Opened bug report here: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6691. For large amounts of real world data, this shouldn't actually matter *that* much, unless your data systematically differs in distribution within the 5 minute bins.